# Jira report to pdf in maven

Tags: html, maven, pdf, jira, maven-changes-plugin

I have a Jira report generated in Maven with the changes plugin, but I want to be able to put this report in a generated PDF file. Unfortunately the maven-pdf-plugin isn't able to generate reports with Maven 3, and it doesn't seem like they are fixing this issue. Are there any other options that achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My work-around is:

1. Generate [Docbook](http://docbook.org/) xml file with [changes:announcement-generate](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/announcement-generate-mojo.html) an a custom [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) template.
2. Generate PDF file with [docbkx-maven-plugin](http://docbkx-tools.sourceforge.net/docbkx-samples/manual.html).